# Missing WSDL error.. Trying to add functionality to an existing WSDL

Tags: maven, soapui, mule

I'm currently trying to add functionality to a WSDL.. I think I did all the changes necessary but  after a Soap request I get an error. Out of curiosity I tried to test the original WSDL and it doesn't work anymore, I get the following fault:

```
<faultstring> Message part {urn:bar:foo}AddRequest was not recognized.  (Does it exist in service WSDL?)</faultstring>
```

I know the request in question is there, but for some reason is not being recognized.
I reverted all changes in all files (hoping it was just a simple mismatch on the WSDL signature) but I didn't have much luck. any ideas?

I'm really new to all these technologies, any help is welcome.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<mule-project xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.com/tooling/project" runtimeId="org.mule.servers.3.2.0.CE">
    <name>cdms</name>
    <description></description>
</mule-project>
```

Comment: Mule version & config please otherwise impossible to help.

Comment: oh yes! Mule: mule-enterprise-standalone-3.2.1 and for config I don't think there's much.. sorry I'm a mule newbie

Comment: Sorry man, without your application config, it's impossible to know what's going on there.

Comment: is the config just in the .project file?

Comment: The Mule XML configuration of your application.

Comment: This is *not* a Mule configuration file. This is a Studio specific file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake, it was a very obvious thing too :@

I was using the wrong endpoint in soapUI call, so of course I was getting a response but by using the wrong endpoint Mule didn't recognized the WSDL and thus returned a fault